# Two "different" call of the same expression give two different results... why?

Tags: functions

Consider the following code:

```
func1[x_]:=Sinc[x];

    fourier1D[n_,Lperiodization_]=FourierCoefficient[func1[x],x, n,FourierParameters->{1,2*Pi/Lperiodization}];
    L=10;

    N[fourier1D[0, L]]
    0.624146 + 0. I

    N[FourierCoefficient[func1[x], x, 0, 
      FourierParameters -> {1, 2*Pi/L}]]
    0.309986
```

Why when I call the function fourier1D it returns me a different result than when I call directly what is inside my function ?

All parameters are absolutely identical in the two different call. Where is the problem ?

I guess it is something obvious but I'm stuck on it for hours now...!

Comment: use `SetDelayed (:=)` when you define `fourier1D`?

Comment: `=` is not the same as `:=` in `fourier1D`. What's happening is that that line is first evaluating the `FourierCoefficient` expression and _then_ substituting in the values for `n` and `Lperiodization`. Apparently that gets a different branch cut than doing it directly?

Comment: @kglr the problem is that I really want to pre-compute the result so that the rest of my script is faster. What is the problem with the "=" here ? I don't see why this pre-affectation causes problem ?

Comment: @StarBucK Because without exact values of n and L, `FourierCoefficient` can't pick smart branch cuts for your problem. Thus, it tries to generalize, but if you then apply the substitution and accidentally cross a discontinuity, the answer could be completely wrong. I'd trust the 0.309986 much more than the 0.624146 here. Using `:=` prevents the pre-computation from making assumptions that later turn out to be unworkable. Save result after substitution, don't save it before.

Comment: @eyorble hmmm I see what you mean. The "problem" I have is that it saves me a lot of computational time to pre compute via the "=". Is there a way to tell mathematica to not do any assumption (like he reasons with Piecewise to avoid branchcutting as you say) ? I hope I am clear in my asking

Comment: I could not tell you exactly why, but applying the option `GenerateConditions->True` seems to correct the result here. The specification of plausible `Assumptions` however simply prevents it from evaluating in the first place. So `GenerateConditions` might be what you're looking for here. Double-check on further data. More strangely, the resulting expression with `GenerateConditions->True` does not actually contain any conditions.

Comment: Perhaps [memoization](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html) is what you are seeking.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Integrate`:

```
fc = Abs[b/(2*Pi)]^((a + 1)/2)*
   Integrate[func1[t]/E^(I*b*n*t), {t, -(Pi/Abs@b), Pi/Abs@b}];
Block[{a, b, n = 0},
 {a, b} = {1, 2*Pi/L};
 fc // N
 ]
(*  0.309986  *)
```